# How can I use SetParent to move a gameobject back to his original place in the hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have the original hierarchy for example:

```
Cube1
 Cube2
```

And I did on Cube2:

```
transform.SetParent(null);
```

Now the Hierarchy is looks like:

```
Cube1
Cube2
```

But if I want now to move back Cube2 to his original place ?

```
Cube1
 Cube2
```

And same for other objects if they were children of children or sub parents and I move a group of objects and made them all SetParent(null) and now I want them all to return them to they original place.

Answer (score 3):

You find the "Cube1" GameObject which was the parent:

```
GameObject cube1 = GameObject.Find("Cube1");
```

You call the `SetParent` function again but with the "Cube1" Transform in the argument passed to it:

```
transform.SetParent(cube1.transform);
```

Comment: Alternatively to `GameObject.Find` you could store a reference using `prevParent = transform.parent` and then set it back using `transform.SetParent(prevParent);`

Comment: That would work too. Based on OP's last question, I think there more than 1 objects so showing how to find it is important. A public variable assigned from the Editor would also work. As long as you have the reference to the supposed parent object, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this for the tutorial of our game. Basically the purpose is to have a game object from the UILayer be transfer to the TutorialLayer.

1. In the TutorialHandler of our game I made a `Dictionary<int, GameObject> originalParent`
2. `PutToLayer(GameObject targret)` function transfers target to the TutorialLayer and I store the original parent to the dictionary, using the target's instance id as key originalParent.Add(target.GetInstanceId()), target.transform.parent)
3. Returning the trarget to the original parent can be done by getting it from the dictionary
   `Transform origParent = originalParent[target.GetInstanceId()];`
   `target.SetParent(origParent);`

This way, you can transfer game objects to different parents while keeping track of the original parent

Answer (score 0):

I think a nicer solution wouldn't involve any hard-coded names or inspector assigning since those implementations are prone to breaking when you rename or shift objects around.

I'd create a new component that remembers the original parent and then simply leaves it or rejoins it when you tell it to.

```
public class RoamingChild : MonoBehaviour {

     private Transform _parent;

     public void Awake () {
          _parent = transform.parent;
     }

     //Leave the parent and go off on its own!
     public void Leave () { 
          transform.SetParent(null);
     }

     //Come back to the parent!
     public void Rejoin () {
          transform.SetParent(_parent);
     }
}
```

---

It might also be useful for the `Child` to come back to the same position within the `Parent`. So `Child2` can leave and then rejoin the parent as the second child.

You could add this functionality by also remembering the [SiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetSiblingIndex.html).

```
public class RoamingSibling : MonoBehaviour {

     private Transform _parent;
     private int _siblingIndex;

     public void Awake () {
          _parent = transform.parent;
          _siblingIndex = transform.GetSiblingIndex();
     }

     //Leave the parent and go off on its own!
     public void Leave () { 
          transform.SetParent(null);
     }

     //Come back to the parent!
     public void Rejoin () {
          transform.SetParent(_parent);
          transform.SetSiblingIndex(_siblingIndex);
     }
}
```